# Is the information that a human brain (and body) "contains" superflorous to the information contained within the atoms of the body?

Tags: black-holes, information

Layman here.

I recently watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I55e6chHUs0&feature=youtu.be) talking about Stephen Hawking's theory of hairy black holes. The speaker mentions, as I've heard before, that once "something" has entered a blackhole its information is thought to be lost.

To get to the point without trying to confuse my train of thought; so particles such as electrons, quarks, bosons?, etc all have some "basic" information they hold, spin, momentum, speed, etc (I'll call this "basic information", each counts as 1 basic information units (I know there is a word for this/these)). I would assume that it is accepted that when many of these particles form some object, say a human, they hold more information than just the sum of the basic information units. For example, if a single electron holds 7 basic information units, then a 2 electron system would hold more than 14 basic information units.

The real point of that paragraph, do multi-particle systems hold more information than their constituent parts?

Following from that, is it proven that this information is real so to say? My counter argument is that if there is some multi-particle system all of the particles would have to "feel" each other (Electrons "feel" each others charge, mass, etc). As a result of all the particles in the system interacting with each other through some long chain of cause and effect, they have some given state at a given time that is unique to the objects make up at that given time.

Disregarding what happens within a blackhole, say you take an object put it in a blackhole, and collect every and only every particle that made up that object from the blackhole's radiation, could you not theoretically reconstruct it perfectly if the unique state of each particle was maintained through its insertion and collection? Because a given unique state could, in my reasoning, only exist if every other particle were as it was at a given time.

Meaning that the "extra information" (the information units above 14 in the two electron system) is simply superfluous to the basic information?

Comment: What do you mean by object? How complex of an object. Lowering entropy?

Comment: Just any multi-particle system from 2 to 2 quintillion.

Comment: You don't have to take the black hole information debate too seriously... physicists don't know anything for real about it, that is why there is a hot debate about it in the first place. If you replace "black hole" with "cup of milk coffee", you are back to the same debate that we had during the second half of the 19th century about the discrepancy between thermodynamics/statistical mechanics and classical mechanics. Unfortunately, Hawking and brethren didn't pay very close attention to that in school and they think they have come up with a new debate, but it's just a replay.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps a different way to frame your question is, how can we define information such that it will be conserved? We like conservation laws in physics, so we often define quantities in such a way that they will be conserved. Information will require some special handling to get it to be conserved, because it is normally associated with entropy (indeed there is such a thing as "information entropy", which essentially distinguishes between what we know about a system and what we don't know about it, and lumps all the information that we don't know into "information entropy"). Entropy is not conserved, indeed we have a law that it increases, but this just means that if we group systems based on what we know about them, and let what we don't know about them be regarded as a set of equally likely substates, then the overall probability the system will end up in one of our groups is simply proportional to the number of equally likely substates in each group. The information we need to assign the groups comes from what we know, the number of substates in each group comes from all the things we don't know, and the natural logarithm of that number of substates is called the information entropy. In that light, we see that the second law of thermodynamics is simply the law of large numbers-- systems involving many trials will tend toward the most likely outcomes, and the most likely outcome is that our system will end up in a group with more unknown substates than the group it started out in. So given all this, has someone defined information in a way that produces a conservation law? Well, the one situation in which entropy is conserved is in "reversible" systems, where whatever happens can also unhappen just as easily. So I think that would be a starting point to trying to create a law of conservation of information-- think of information in the context of completely reversible occurences. Since the basic laws of physics are all reversible (except in certain specialized circumstances), I would tend to say that defining information in terms of complete information, where you don't distinguish between what is known and what is not known, would yield a type of information that is conserved in that sense. This is tantamount to the concept of absolute determinism, but gets deeply into the philosophy of science to try and assert whether or not the universe is actually deterministic! So the way I'd put it is, it might be possible to define a type of information that is conserved, but it might not end up being a very useful way to think about information-- too much sacrifice in utility to get that conservation law. Instead, information entropy, where we distinguish what we know from what we don't know, is the way we use information in practical applications, and that is not conserved-- systems tend to "get away from us" in terms of what we can know about them, and it is useful for us to recognize and respond to this effect.

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/conservation-of-information-law.607233/

Ken G. May 19, 2012(Pulled from another Forum)